# Semaphores working when running as superuser,fail to work otherwise

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, fork, semaphore

I have this simple code where I initialize a system V semaphore so my 2 processes print the following code 10 times : "abcd" . The first process prints the "ab" string whilst the other one prints the "cd\n" string.
So when I execute it as a superuser everything works fine,but when I am not using the sudo command to execute it I have an unexpected output.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include "display.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

key_t key1 = 12345;
int semid;
unsigned short semval;
int  i;
int childpid;

struct sembuf wit,signal;

wit.sem_num = 0;
wit.sem_op = -1;
wit.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

signal.sem_num = 0;
signal.sem_op = 1;
signal.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

semid = semget(key1,1,IPC_CREAT);
//  printf("Allocating the semaphore: %s\n",strerror(errno));

semval = 1;
semctl(semid,0,SETVAL,semval);
//  printf("Setting semaphore value to %d: %s\n",semval,strerror(errno));

semval = semctl(semid,0,GETVAL);
//  printf("Initialized Semaphore value to %d: %s\n",semval,strerror(errno));
sleep(1);
childpid = fork();

if(childpid==0){         /*process 2 */
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        semop(semid,&wit,1);
        semctl(semid,0,GETVAL,&semval);
        display("cd\n");
        semop(semid,&signal,1);
    }
    semctl(semid,0,GETVAL,&semval);
    return 0;
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    semop(semid,&wit,1);   /* process 1*/
    semctl(semid,0,GETVAL,&semval);
    display("ab");
    semop(semid,&signal,1);
}
semctl(semid,0,GETVAL,&semval);
sleep(1);
semctl(semid,0,IPC_RMID);
//  printf("\nSemaphore removed from the System = %s\n",strerror(errno));
return 0;
}
```

So when i execute my code with the "sudo ./mycodehere" command everything goes smoothly and the output is correct:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

but if i execute it normally, "./mycodehere" the result is not the same:

```
acbda
bcadb
acbda
bcadb
acbda
bcadb
acbd
cd
cd
cd
```

Can someone explain me why is this happening,and if possible,where should i look to fix it?Thanks a lot in advance!
Almost forgot.The display.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "display.h"

void display(char *str)
{
  char *p;
  for (p=str; *p; p++)
  {
    write(1, p, 1);
    usleep(100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior according to `man semctl: [...]This  function  has  three  or  four arguments, depending on cmd.  When there are four, the fourth has the type union semun[...]`.

Comment: explain me,what do you mean by this?

Comment: Did you check result of `semop()` and `semct()` calls inside parent and child code? BTW, `sudo` gives you super**user** rights, super**visor** is different thing.

Comment: I will try that,thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
semid = semget(key1,1,IPC_CREAT);
```

fails to set the semaphore permissions properly.  The permissions are all zero.

Per the `semget` [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/semget.html):

> The low-order 9 bits of *sem_perm.mode* shall be set equal to the
>   low-order 9 bits of *semflg*.

And per the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html):

> Upon creation, the least significant 9 bits of the argument semflg
>   define the permissions (for owner, group and others) for the semaphore
>   set.  These bits have the same format, and the same meaning, as the
>   mode argument of open(2) (though the execute permissions are not
>   meaningful for semaphores, and write permissions mean permission to
>   alter semaphore values).

Your code needs to be something like this:

```
semid = semget(key1,1,IPC_CREAT | 0660 );
```

But now your semaphore likely already exists with the wrong permissions.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I remove the semaphore in the end of the code,so by changing that,the problem was solved.Very helpful!